# Unable to get actionbar subtitle id

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textview

I want to set following property to action bar sub tiltle:

```
    mAppSubtitle.setText(title);
    mAppSubtitle.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    mAppSubtitle.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(1);
    mAppSubtitle.setFocusable(true);
    mAppSubtitle.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mAppSubtitle.requestFocus();
    mAppSubtitle.setSingleLine(true);
    mAppSubtitle.setSelected(true);
    mAppSubtitle.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
    mAppSubtitle.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

I am trying following code to get to get id of actionbar subtitle:

```
    int subtitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_subtitle", "id", "android");
    TextView mAppSubtitle=(TextView)findViewById(subtitleId);
```

But I am always getting null pointer exception at 1st line:

mAppSubtitle.setText(title);

Comment: where do you initialized mAppSubtitle?

Comment: I have written in a question

Comment: Why you don't use `actionBar.setSubTitle()` method?

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, in the onCreate method after calling setContentView().

You can change your apps actionBar subtitle like this:
FIRST MAKE SURE YOUR APP THEME HAS AN ACTIONBAR! 
IF YOUR THEME SAYS NO.ACTION BAR you will not see anything!

```
getActionBar.setSubtitle(subtitle);
```